# annotate windows folders

Tags: windows-explorer

Is there a way to annotate folders, with the annotations showing up in windows explorer?

Ideally, the annotations should be visible as tooltip and in the properties dialog.

Installing additional software at the clients would not be a problem, btu it should work for folders on the network, too. Server is W2K3, Clients are XP and W7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for what is called an "InfoTip". An example of this is shown below:

[image: Example of an InfoTip]

You can add an InfoTip to a folder by adding an `InfoTip` entry to the `.ShellClassInfo` section of the `desktop.ini` contained in the folder.

An example of the contents of such a file:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=Some sensible information.
```

Note, the folder needs to be marked as a system folder for the text to be shown. This can be accomplished by running the following command:

```
attrib +s <folder_name>
```

For further information, and more help in doing it, see the following:

- [Customizing Folders with Desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144102(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Adding Tooltips/Info tips to any folder](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/109834-adding-tooltips-info-tips-any-folder.html)

Comment: +1 (tomorrow, out of votes now) Didn't know such feature was built-in. :-)

Comment: Additional info (in the year 2021, Windows 10). 1) the folder does not need to be System, but you need to R-Click it in Explorer, Properties/Customize/Change Icon. Select any icon from the list. It will add "desktop.ini" hidden system file to your folder. 2) edit this file by giving command "notepad desktop.ini" from command prompt, and add InfoTip as described above. 3) Now, add column "Comments" to columns that Explorer displays in Details view -- you will see the text that you typed in InfoTip in this Comments column in Explorer.

Comment: Addition to my additional comments: 4) remove hidden and system flags from the desktop.ini file (attrib -h -s desktop.ini) - now you can easily change the folder's comment because this file becomes visible in Explorer. Note: Windows needs some time to update the comment in the Explorer after you changed it in desktop.ini - 20-30 sec or so sometimes.